# Is it possible to temporarily disable exception dialogues being shown to the user

Tags: sockets, delphi, indy

I'm using GStack.ResolveHost from IDStack to get IP address from a hostname, 
so I can ping the IP address & check I have a connection before doing more involved tasks like getting internet time or connecting to a mailhost.
So I'm trying to code this in a way which can cope with loss of connection without throwing up error messages to the user. The next part IcmpSendEcho copes ok with no connection, it's this part of getting the IP address I'm not happy with.

Even using `try/except`, the error dialogue is still shown to the user at runtime, in IDE or from the .exe.
Given that I can't programmatically guard against things like network failure is there a way to disable the 'host error, socket not found' being shown to the user, (and possibly filling the screen with dialogues for unattended programs)?
Or am I barking up the wrong tree?
I tried `{$WARNINGS OFF} {$WARNINGS ON}` but they don't apply to 'Host error - socket not found'
I fear someone will say I'm making a mistake using the built in Indy methods & I should use Jedi code library..?

```
function TInternetTools.HostNameToIPAddr(const AHostName:String; var AIPAddress :string): Boolean;  
begin
  TIdStack.IncUsage;                        
  try
    AIPAddress := GStack.ResolveHost(AHostName);  
    Result := true;
  except
    Result := false;
  end;
  TIdStack.DecUsage;
end;
```

Comment: On my machine this code runs without issue. It's quite possible the error is not generated by Delphi, but by your OS. There is no reason the socket should not be found. If I disable network access I get an error in the IDE, but not at runtime. The try-except swallows all error messages (as expected). Are you **really** getting this error when running it as a stand-alone program (i.e. not from the Delphi IDE)?

Comment: Pointless to check connectivity before you do work. Successful check does not mean connectivity will endure. Remove that code completely and handle errors in your normal work. Which you have to do anyway.

Comment: `'Host error - socket not found'` is NOT an Indy error message. This code *IS NOT* what is displaying the error message to the user. Even if an exception were being raised, this code is swallowing all exceptions, as Johan said. You need to debug the code and find the true source of the error message.

Comment: On a side note, at the very least, you should wrap `TIdStack.IncUsage()` itself in a `try/except` (in case WinSock fails to initialize), and use a `try/finally` to call `TIdStack.DecUsage()`.